# Why do loudspeakers/microphones use radial magnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, acoustics

Loudspeakers and dynamic microphones both use a rotationally symmetrical magnet, with the voice coil slotting into a circular gap.

But this means the magnetic field of the voice coil is axial, and perpendicular to the radial magnetic field of the permanent magnet.  Isn't this inefficient?  Wouldn't the force be stronger if the permanent magnetic field were also axial?

Answer (score 4):

Force gets generated by the interaction of the current flow through the coil and the magnetic flux of the motor. Hence you design to have current and flux to be perpendicular to each other and the motor is designed to concentrate all the magnetic flux in the gap.

The current in the coil does indeed create a magnetic field as well, but that is an undesirable effect that hampers the motion of the coil, since it works against the magnetic field of the permanent magnet. In a well designed transducer this field is relatively small, so it doesn't matter much.

Comment: "but that is an undesirable effect that hampers the motion of the coil, since it works against the magnetic field of the permanent magnet"  But the whole purpose of the coil is to work against the magnetic field of the permanent magnet.  That's how it works, no?  The coil produces an (axial) magnetic field that alternately attracts or repels the permanent magnet's field.

Comment: @endolith: Not really. The driving force, $F$, is the Lorentz Force: $F = B \cdot l \cdot i $ where $B$ is the magnetic field (of the permanent magnet), $l$ the length of the coil and $i$ the current through the coil. So the basic mechanism is  a magnetic field exerting a force on moving electrons. It's not two magnetic fields interacting with each other.